# Create an update function for front-end react native app

Tags: react-native, react-redux, lodash

I am developing a front end mobile application with react-native and redux implementation. I had successfully pulled all the necessary real APIs. Now I want to create a function that can update the student's info. Fyi, I'm developing a student information system, so there's info like address and email that need to be updated if changes occur. I don't know how to do it, I heard people uses "lodash" which I dunno what it is for. And how do I save the updated changes?

Answer (score 1):

To update state of redux, it is good idea to use helper like react-addons-update or immutability-helper. update() provides simple syntactic pattern to make writing state update code easier. Eg:

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

function handleUpdateMydata(state, action){
   return update(state,{
      myData:{
         $set:action.payload
      }
   })
}
```

To ensure your state is permanent store, you may use redux-persist

Answer (score 1):

lodash is a library that is used for dealing with the arrays and objects. if you wanna know more about its content see the documentation here
[Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4)

Now coming on to your real problem,since you are using redux I think you should create an action that would update your student details in the database